# how do i fix "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer" that i get from luaJ

Tags: eclipse, luaj

I tried to get luaJ to work but when i add luaj .jar files to modularpath
i get this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for D:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\luaj-3.0.1\lib\luaj-jse-3.0.1.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: luajc.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

I have already tried to search anywhere for this issue. My project is using java 15.

Comment: You cannot put this JAR on the modulepath since the class `luajc` is contained in the default package which works on the classpath, but is not allowed on the modulepath. In addition, two modules/JARs must not contain classes of the same package. As long as these conditions do not apply, you cannot move the JAR from the classpath to the modulepath.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently i have put every luaj jar file at once.